# parSequence and parTraverse in tagless final

Tags: scala, cats-effect

Using tagless final (without using IO, but rather a generic F) how can I abstract over something like this:

```
def doSomething(s: String): IO[Unit] = ???

List("authMethods", "secretEngines", "plugins", "CAs", "common").parTraverse(doSomething)
```

The closest I can get is using `parTraverseN` from the Concurrent object, but I assume this will run concurrently instead of in parallel (as in [parallelism](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency/basics.html#parallelism)). It also forces me to choose an `n` where as `parTraverse` does not.

The size of the list is just an example, it could be way bigger. `doSomething` is a pure function, multiple executions of it can run in parallel without problems.

Ideally, given that `doSomething` returns `IO[Unit]` I would like to abstract over `parTraverse_` to an `F` with the correct typeclass instance.

Comment: In my answer below I'm assuming that you mean "`doSomething` returns `F[Unit]`" in the last paragraph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a similar complete working example:

```
import cats.Applicative
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.foldable._

trait Service[F[_]] {
  val items = List("authMethods", "secretEngines", "plugins", "CAs", "common")

  def doSomething(s: String): F[Unit] = ???

  def result(implicit F: Applicative[F]): F[Unit] =
    items.traverse_(doSomething)
}
```

If you want to use `parTraverse_` here, the minimal changes necessary would look something like this:

```
import cats.{Applicative, Parallel}
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.parallel._

trait Service[F[_]] {
  val items = List("authMethods", "secretEngines", "plugins", "CAs", "common")

  def doSomething(s: String): F[Unit] = ???

  def result(implicit F: Applicative[F], P: Parallel[F]): F[Unit] =
    items.parTraverse_(doSomething)
}
```

Alternatively you could use `Parallel.parTraverse_(items)(doSomething)` and skip the `syntax` import. Both approaches require a `Foldable` instance for `List` (provided here by the `cats.instances.list._` import, which will no longer be necessary in [Cats 2.2.0](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases/tag/v2.2.0-M1)), and a `Parallel` instance for `F`, which you get via the `P` constraint.

(Note that the `Applicative` constraint on `result` is no longer necessary in the second version, but that's only because this is a very simple example—I'm assuming your real code relies on something like `Sync` instead, and will need both that and `Parallel`.)

This answer needs a couple of footnotes, though. The first is that it might not actually be a good thing that `parTraverse_` doesn't make you specify a bound in the way that `parTraverseN` does, and may result in excessive memory use, etc. (but this will depend on e.g. the expected size of your lists and the kind of work `doSomething` is doing, and is probably outside the scope of the question).

The second footnote is that "parallel" in the sense of the `Parallel` type class is more general than the "parallel" in the parallel-vs.-concurrent distinction in the Cats "Concurrency Basics" document. The `Parallel` type class models a very generic kind of logical parallelism that also encompasses [error accumulation](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2019/09/11/why-parallel/), for example. So when you write:

> I assume this will run concurrently instead of in parallel (as in [parallelism](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency/basics.html#parallelism)).

…your assumption is correct, but not exactly because the `parTraverseN` method is on `Concurrent` instead of `Parallel`; note that `Concurrent.parTraverseN` still requires a `Parallel` instance. When you see `par` or the `Parallel` type class in the context of `cats.effect.Concurrent`, you should think of concurrency, not "parallelism" in the "Concurrency Basics" sense.

Comment: So if `par` or the `Parallel` type class in the context of `cats.effect.Concurrent` means concurrency, can I assume `par` in the context of `Parallel` means parallelism?
In your solution all the imports are from cats not cats effect, can cats run things in parallel on its own, aka without needing the cats-effect machinery? What am I missing?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [this blog post](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2019/09/11/why-parallel/). `cats.Parallel` is a very general thing—on its own it's not really about "running" anything at all. `Either[E, *]` has a `Parallel` instance, for example, and in that context `Parallel` means "combine these validation operation results and accumulate errors", without having anything to say about whether the computations happen sequentially or in parallel or which threads they run on.